# Chat won't scroll in Chromium on Ubuntu

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I'm using Chromium version 58.0.3029.110 built on Ubuntu, running on Ubuntu 16.10 (64-bit). Chat doesn't scroll on new messages, mine or otherwise.

Observations:

- This has been going on for a long while now, every time I logged in from Ubuntu in the past couple months at least.
- I can reproduce this from an incognito window with no extensions on.
- I don't have anything funky in my hosts file or any other system-level things like that.
- It does *not* reproduce on Firefox on the same machine for me.

Comment: This happens to me sometimes in Ubuntu, Firefox 55b0(1,2,3). I think it happens most frequently after I've had chat open in a background tab for a long time.

Comment: This happens to me in the mobile view on my Andriod tablet with the Chrome browser.

Comment: Anyone who can reproduce this - do you see any errors in the console when scrolling (or just loading the page)?

Comment: This is happening on windows now too

Comment: Same here on canary build: Version 61.0.3147.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit). Nothing in console

Comment: Same here (Version 61.0.3150.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit) on macOS). I didn't have the console open, but will leave it open for a while.

Comment: To anyone reporting on beta/dev/canary versions (currently 60/61) - those are not supported - we never did support browsers in beta/dev/canary versions precisely because they break things.

Comment: Although true. If the canary dies it would be wise to check before things land in stable and it's broken for everyone.

Comment: @Oded Seems to have been fixed by the latest jQuery upgrade. Tagging [meta-tag:status-completed].