# Chat not scrolling to latest message any more and there are hundred of errors

Tags: support, bug, chat

This is the error I get in the console (Chrome 60 on a Mac):

[image]

Whenever I go into chat it doesn't scroll to the bottom and any new messages I have to manually scroll.

I tried refreshing multiple times to no avail...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chat won't scroll in Chromium on Ubuntu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351032/chat-wont-scroll-in-chromium-on-ubuntu)

Comment: @PaulCrovella not ubuntu. This is MacOs

Comment: enable break on exception and figure out what `data` is, would likely be helpful to diagnosing/fixing.

Comment: @Neal Do you expect it's a different problem?

Comment: @PaulCrovella that user was using a Canary build.. I am using the latest stable version of Chrome.

Comment: I cannot even click on replies to messages, so idk what relates to what.